# USBカメラのサンプリングレート

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ffmpeg

Raspberry Pi3に、USBカメラ　Logcool C920r挿しての映像をYoutubeにストリーミングしようとしています。
ＯＳは専用のDebianです。
C920は、H.264のハードエンコードができるので、以下のコーゴで、そのまま`ffmpeg`を使ってストリーミングしています。

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -f v4l2 -codec:v h264 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -itsoffset 0.5 \
-i /dev/video0 -copyinkf -codec:v copy -codec:a aac -ab 128k -g 60 -strict experimental \
-f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY
```

ただ、サンプリングレートが32000になってしまいます。

`ffmpeg`に`-ar 44100`を追加しても変化はありません。
C920のWinders用の設定ソフトを見ると、48kHz、32kHz、16kHzの設定切り替えができるようなのですが、`-ar 48000`にしてみても変わりません。

サンプルレートを変更する方法は無いでしょうか？

ちなみに、`/proc/asound/C920/stream0`の内容は以下のようになっています。

```
HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-3f980000.usb-1.5, high speed : USB Audio

Capture:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 3
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 16000
    Data packet interval: 1000 us
  Interface 3
    Altset 2
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 24000
    Data packet interval: 1000 us
  Interface 3
    Altset 3
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 32000
    Data packet interval: 1000 us
```

Comment: `/proc/asound/C920/stream0` の内容にサンプリングレート 48kHz の項目が見当たらないので、もしかすると Linux 側のデバイスドライバが 48kHz に対応していないのかもしれません。例えば `-ar 24000` を指定すると 24kHz になるのでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに、-ar 2400なら変更が有効にまりました。このドライバを変更することは出来ないでしょうか？

Comment: わざわざ詳しくテストして戴いてありがとうございました。現在のffmpegは2.6.9でした、upgrade後も変わらないので、最新版ソースからコンパイルしてみます。